# Alter Leaflet L.Icon.Default

Tags: leaflet, icon

How to set the properties of L.Icon.Default.prototype.options? I want to change the size of L.Icon.Default.

Answer (score 3):

Let me quote the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-default):

> In order to change the default icon, just change the properties of `L.Icon.Default.prototype.options` (which is a set of `Icon` options).

If you're fairly new to javascript, this means doing something like:

```
L.Icon.Default.prototype.options = {
    iconUrl: 'whatever.png',
    iconSize: [20, 70],
    iconAnchor: [10, 70],
    // ...etc, with all the L.Icon desired/needed options.
}
```